# How to Login to ORACLE using password and Username name as process arguments?

Tags: windows, oracle, process, oracle-sqldeveloper, runtime.exec

I have a requirement to login to ORACLE DB with pre-entered username and password, I am using SQLdeveloper tool to connect to Oracle.

When I launch **sqldeveloper.exe** it must directly connect me to the Oracle database.  What process arguments should I pass with this process?

I have tried

```
CMD>sqldeveloper.exe Username/Password@server:port:Service
```

It launches Sqldeveloper tool but do not connects to the database

while I am able to connect with the following command 
    CMD>sql.exe Username/Password@server:port:Service

Instead of connecting to the database, it opens worksheets in the tool, like for the above example it opens 
worksheets like username, password etc...

Comment: It won't open the sql developer tool, I am able to connect to through command line, I want to pass the credentials through process arguments.

Comment: sqldeveloper is a gui tool, if you want to connect to oracle in cmd, you can use sqlplus

Comment: @hotfix Yes it is i am able to cconnect to Oracle DB through sqlplus, I just want to connect to sqldeveloper with pre entered credentials, i.e. as a process argument to sqldeveloper.exe

Comment: You can't.  It is a GUI front-end.

Comment: Also note that exposing _any_ credentials in the command line is a HUGE security problem, as commands are often recorded in audit trails or shell histories, or visible to process/environment monitoring tools. It would be more secure to use an Oracle Wallet to store the credentials. This would let you use sqlplus or sqlcl without showing username/password in the command line, but the user would still have to manually click the database connection in SQL Developer to make the connection.

Comment: If your requirement is to do this with SQL Dev, then you must re-think your "requirement". When a command is entered at a command line, the OS is only responsible for locating and launching the binary executable named by the command itself.  Everything following the command itself is made available to the executable - to be processed in whatever manner the executable is coded to do .... or not.  In the cae of SQL Dev, it is simply not coded to do _anything_ with any command-line parms.